# UIButton .normal state strange behavior

Tags: swift

I programically create the button:

```
final class SearchArea: UIView {
    
    private let offset: CGFloat = 5
    
    private(set) lazy var searchRequest = {
        let item = UITextField()
        item.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        item.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        item.clearButtonMode = .always
        item.layer.cornerRadius = offset
        return item
    }()
    
    private(set) lazy var searchButton = {
        let item = UIButton()
        item.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        item.layer.cornerRadius = offset
        item.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "magnifyingglass"), for: .normal)
        return item
    }()

    
    func setupView() {
        
        backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        let safeArea = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide
             
                                    
        addSubview(searchButton)
        searchButton.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithTop(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .alignBottomWithBottom(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .setAspectWidth(ratio: 1)
        )
  
        addSubview(searchRequest)
        searchRequest.addConstraints(
            .alignTopWithTop(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .alignBottomWithBottom(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: safeArea, const: offset),
            .alignTrailingWithLeading(of: searchButton, const: offset)
        )
 
    }
    
}
```

But get a strange behavior - icon is shown only when the button is pressed, all other time it doesn't have image. But it should due to Apple manual:

> static var normal: UIControl.State The normal, or default, state of a control where the control is enabled but neither selected nor highlighted.

So item.setImage(UIImage for: .normal state should work ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because the button have a default tint color `UIColor.systemBlue`, So can NOT see the image with same background.
Try to differentiate button Tint & Background color

Comment: Thank you so much, the image seems invisible because of tint color. It really was a stupid question, sorry.. ((